# smalltalk - get elements from Array

Tags: smalltalk

I have a following problem:

```
t := #(1,2,3)
t at: 1  -> 1
t at: 2  -> #,
```

Thats problem for me, 
how to get following effect:

```
t at 1 -> 1
t at 2 -> 2
```

Answer (score 6):

`#(1,2,3)` is an array literal where elements are separated either by spaces or by type, so in the end you get an array with 5 items two of which are comma symbols: `#,` (`#` is used to show the symbol literal).

You need to define array as `#(1 2 3)`.

There is also an array expression: `{1 . 2 . 3}`, but this is evaluate thing. For example you can do `{1 . 2 . 2 + 4 . a + b}` which you cannot do with literal arrays `#()` as they have to be defined at the compile time. E.g. variables `a` and `b` that I've used are not known during the compile time

Answer (score 5):

OK. Let's take this opportunity to provide a more complete description of literals.

There are several types of literals in Smalltalk

**Integers**

1. *Decimal*

   ```
   10
   -1
   0
   1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   ```
2. *Hexadecimal*

   ```
   16rAB1F
   16r0
   -16rFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
   ```
3. *ScaledDecimal*

   ```
   17s0
   3.14159265s8
   ```
4. *Other*

   ```
   8r7731                             (octal)
   2r1001                             (binary)
   10r99987                           (decimal again!)
   etc.
   ```

**Characters**

```
   $A                                  (uppercase)
   $a                                  (lowercase)
   $                                   (space!)
   $→                                  (unicode)
   $1                                  (not to be confused with 1)
```

**Strings**

```
   ''                                  (empty string)
   ' '                                 (string with 1 space)
   'Hello world'
```

**Symbols**

```
   #hello
   #'hello world'
   #''                                 (empty symbol, not very useful)
   #+
   #1                                  (not the integer 1)
```

**ByteArrays**

```
   #[1 2 3 4]                          (separators are blank)
   #[]                                 (empty ByteArray)
   #[0 0 0 0 255]                      (length is arbitrary)
```

**Arrays**

```
   #(256 16rAB1F 3.14s2 2r1001 $A #this)
```

Note that literal arrays use any kind and number of blanks as separtors

```
   #(256
     16rAB1F
     3.14s2
     2r1001
     $A #this)                         (same as above)
```

Note also that you can compose literals

```
   #[255 16rFF 8r377 2r11111111]       (four times 255)

   #(#[1 2 3] #('string' #symbol))     (arrays of arrays)
```

There is some "tolerance* to relaxed notation

```
   #(symbol) = #(#symbol)              (missing # => symbol)

   #('string' ($a 'a'))                (missing # => array)
```

But not here:

```
   #([1 2 3]) ~= #(#[1 2 3])           (missing # => misinterpreted)
```

However

```
   #(true nil false)                   (pseudo variables ok)
```

But not here!

```
   #(self) = #(#self)                  (missing # => symbol)
```

As you can see there are a couple of inconsistencies:

**a**. While pseudo variables `true`, `false` and `nil` are accepted as literals inside arrays, the pseudo variables `self` and `super` are interpreted as Symbols (using the more general rule for unqualified strings.)

**b**. While it is not mandatory to write #( for starting a nested array in an array and the parenthesis suffices, it is mandatory to write #[ for starting a nested ByteArray.